# What can I do with my Samsung Gear 2 Neo? - I have a Nexus 5X & Samsung Tab S2 9.7

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-gear

A while back I got a Samsung Gear 2 Neo, when I had a Galaxy device to pair it with.

Unfortunately, my phone got stolen.

I waited for the Nexus 5X to be my replacement phone and also got a Samsung Tab S2 9.7.

I was surprised that the Gear 2 Neo is not supported by the very recent Tab S2 9.7. It still makes no sense. The Gear Manager doesn't even install.

So my Gear 2 Neo is just sitting and still new.

**How can I use of it?** It seems such a waste and rather insincere that Samsung does not support the Gear 2 Neo on even recent devices.

Comment: @Imbolord Not quite... Gear 2 is different from OG Gear in that it runs Tizen and there's no Null ROM for it (there is an Android port but one without phone connection capability, AFAIK).

Comment: Yeah you are right. Sorry

Comment: This isnt duplicate. I don't have a Nexus 4 and I am also using a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 9.7. You didnt understand the full question